# DirectX: Antialiasing doesn´t work

Tags: directx

I just want to enable Antialiasing in DirectX9, but it doesn´t seem to do much, and the text drawn with ID3DXFont.DrawText(...) looks jagged too.

Here is the initialization-part

```
pDirect3D = Direct3DCreate9( D3D_SDK_VERSION);
memset(&presentParameters, 0, sizeof(_D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS_));
presentParameters.BackBufferCount = 1;
presentParameters.BackBufferWidth = 800;
presentParameters.BackBufferHeight = 500;

presentParameters.MultiSampleType = D3DMULTISAMPLE_NONMASKABLE;
presentParameters.MultiSampleQuality = 2;

presentParameters.SwapEffect = D3DSWAPEFFECT_DISCARD;
presentParameters.hDeviceWindow = hWnd;
presentParameters.Flags = 0;
presentParameters.FullScreen_RefreshRateInHz = D3DPRESENT_RATE_DEFAULT;
presentParameters.PresentationInterval = D3DPRESENT_INTERVAL_DEFAULT;
presentParameters.BackBufferFormat = D3DFMT_R5G6B5;
presentParameters.EnableAutoDepthStencil = TRUE;
presentParameters.AutoDepthStencilFormat = D3DFMT_D16;
presentParameters.Windowed = TRUE;
pDirect3D->CreateDevice(D3DADAPTER_DEFAULT, D3DDEVTYPE_HAL, hWnd,D3DCREATE_SOFTWARE_VERTEXPROCESSING, &presentParameters, &pDevice);
pDevice->SetRenderState(D3DRS_CULLMODE, D3DCULL_NONE);

pDevice->SetRenderState(D3DRS_MULTISAMPLEANTIALIAS, TRUE);
```

Is there something I do wrong?

```
ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);
UpdateWindow(hWnd);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, text isn't anti-aliased by mutli-sampling, secondly a `MultiSampleQuality` of 2 is barely noticeable. Try a 4 or 8 ensure that the result is achieved, try toggling and watch the jagged edges.

You should checkout the AntiAlias sample provided in the DirectX SDK for details about setting this up properly.

Answer (score 1):

I am creating text with meshes (**D3DXCreateTextW**), and I notice a significant difference when MultiSampling, even at low quality levels. With any kind of MultiSampling, the text and other lines are smooth, whereas they are jagged without MultiSampling.

Use **CheckDeviceMultiSampleType** to confirm that your video card does accept the type and level that you are requesting.